# using discord.py how do you get a list of all the members on a discord server

Tags: python, discord.py

Right now I have this:

```py
  for guild in client.guilds:
      for member in guild.members:
```

and this:

```py
  client.users
```

but it only retrieves the bot's info

I want to get all the users/members on my server

Comment: Welcome to Stack Katie! Are these pieces of code in a command or an `on_message` event? Thanks in advance

Comment: pls explain us more what u exactly want to do , reply me back when you are ready

Comment: Hi I have a message from a client.author that signals retrieving all of the members on the server with a specific role. From there I am going to make a channel for each member with that role.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably run this:

```
for guild in client.guilds:
    for member in guild.members:
        print(member.name)
```

to get all the member names in the console